# Actualizar lista a partir de otra lista

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, linq

Trabajo con Visual Studio 2015

Tengo una lista A la cual quiero actualizar desde una lista B

```
foreach (var item in entity.ProductoCatalogos)
            {
                foreach (var asignado in _listProductoCatalogos)
                {
                    asignado.ProductoCatalogoId = item.ProductoCatalogoId;
                    asignado.Id = item.CatalogoId;
                }
            }
```

Tengo dos registros en cada lista he notado que me asigna los datos cuatro veces que entra al segundo `foreach` lo que yo esperaba es que como tengo 2 registros entre solo dos veces.

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar usar LINQ.

```
_listProductoCatalogos = entity.ProductoCatalogos.select(
       i => new <ObjetoDeLaLista>{ Id  = i.CatalogoId, ProductoCatalogoId = i.ProductoCatalogoId} ).ToList();
```

http://www.tuprogramacion.com/glosario/que-es-linq/

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera, necesita primero validar por alguna condición para que me asigne los datos de una lista a otra.

```
foreach (var item in entity.ProductoCatalogos)
            {
                foreach (var asignado in _listProductoCatalogos)
                {
                    if (item.ProductoId == asignado.ProductoId)
                    {
                        asignado.ProductoCatalogoId = item.ProductoCatalogoId;
                        asignado.Id = item.CatalogoId;
                    }
                }
            }
```